# cannot install pyimagej on python

Tags: python, imagej, pyimagej

I need to write a code using jupyter notebook but need imagej packages.
I installed pyimagej using several commands

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyimagej
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pyimagej
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pyimagej
```

But I always get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ij'
when I try

```
from ij import IJ
```

I know that I can use imagej editor but I need to use jupyter notebook. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
conda create -n imagej pyimagej
```

Answer (score 0):

We have recently improved our documentation on how to use PyImageJ. It looks like you were successful in installing the software, but you did not yet initialize PyImageJ. Checkout the [How to initialize PyImageJ](https://pyimagej.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Initialization.html). If you have trouble initializing PyImageJ, you might need to view the [installation](https://pyimagej.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Install.html) documentation.

But assuming you have installed PyImageJ and activated your environment, a typical script looks something like this:

```py
import imagej

# initialize PyImageJ
ij = imagej.init('sc.fiji:fiji', mode='interactive')
print(f"ImageJ Version: {ij.getVersion()}")

# The original ImageJ "IJ" is a property of the initialized "ij" object.
print(dir(ij.IJ))
```

Hope that helps!